# how to make Substring on field on crystalreport?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

how to make Substring on field on crystalreport ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your report, make a calculated value field, and in the evaluation function call the substring subroutine using your field as a parameter as appropriate.

Then just insert your calculated fiend into the report.

There are probably a couple other ways of doing it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mid function